# React Native - npm Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I have install react-native with the manual from https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. 
If I run `npx react-native init name` (create a new project) or `npm install` (in a existing project) I get always the error:

> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

My operating system is Linux Manjaro.

Comment: try to do `npm cache clean` and if it doesn't let you add force: `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I have already try this, but it doesnt works after run `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: This suggested running `npm cache verify` instead, which solved the problem for me - after that, running `npx react-native init MyApp` worked.